# How to change the default location of the Puppet files on a Vagrant VM?

Tags: wordpress, workflow, vagrant, puppet

I'm in the process of ditching MAMP in favor of a Vagrant Ubuntu VM + Puppet for my Wordpress development workflow. Ultimately, I would like to reuse the puppet provisionning on the staging and production machines.

Vagrant defaults to running the Puppet files (modules, manifests, hiera.yaml) under `/tmp/vagrant-puppet-3`. However, my understanding is that on a real server one would put these files under the default Puppet directory which is `/etc/puppet/`.

I understand that Puppet will work fine under `/tmp/vagrant-puppet-3`, however I would like my developement machine to be as close as possible to the future staging / production machines.

So ... my queston is : How can you get Vagrant to create and run the puppet files from `/etc/puppet/` ?

Answer (score 0):

The Vagrant Puppet provisioner has three variables of interest.  You can specify the `manifest_file` to identify the starting manifest, the `manifests_path` to identify the manifests directory and the `modules_path` to provide a hash of module paths.  For your example, the relevant portion of the `vagrantfile` might look like this:

```
local.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
   puppet.manifests_path = "/etc/puppet/manifests"
   puppet.module_path = "/etc/puppet/modules"
   puppet.manifest_file = "/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp"
   puppet.options = [
      '--verbose',
      '--debug',
   ]
end
```

More details here: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/puppet_apply.html.

Comment: I was under the impression that these variables referenced host directories rather than VM directories. Just to be sure I tried what you have suggested and vagrant throws the following error : `The manifests path specified for Puppet does not exist: /etc/puppet/manifests`.

Answer (score 0):

One option here is to use a tool like [librarian-puppet](http://librarian-puppet.com/) to auto-install your Modules into `/etc/puppet/modules/` on the Vagrant VM. Librarian-puppet is able to download specific versions of any Puppet modules from GitHub or PuppetForge.

Here's a wonderful example of how you could implement this in practice (including a sample VagrantFile, etc.): https://github.com/purple52/librarian-puppet-vagrant

In the above example, pay close attention to the [`main.sh` shell provisioning script](https://github.com/purple52/librarian-puppet-vagrant/blob/master/shell/main.sh) for Vagrant. It is what actually installs `librarian-puppet` on the VM, and then calls `librarian-puppet install` (to install the configured modules).

After `librarian-puppet` has initialized the VM, you can simply use the normal Puppet provisioning in Vagrant to actually load/run the modules, e.g.

```
# This assumes you have a "puppet/manifests/main.pp" script 
# under your vagrant folder
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.manifests_path = "puppet/manifests"
  puppet.manifest_file  = "main.pp"
end
```

Comment: I understand the usefullness of librarian-puppet (I've actually been exploring r10k which has some similar functionality). However the example you provide only solves part of the issue. The modules are loaded from `/ect/puppet/modules` but the manifest is still a vagrant managed file copied from the host to the VM under `/tmp/vagrant-puppet-3`. I would like to have all puppet related files (modules + manifests) executed by vagrant on the VM under `/ect/puppet/`.

Comment: You could just have a simple Vagrant [shell provisioning script](https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/provisioning/shell.html) copy your manifest from `/tmp/vagrant-puppet-3` over to `/etc/puppet/`

Comment: Another option altogether is, if your Puppet scripts are under source control (e.g. in GitHub or similar), you could create a Vagrant provisioning script which pulls them down from source control (e.g. `git clone`) into `/etc/puppet/` directly.